# Why is width:100% relative to screen when within media query

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

If I have want to have the following layout:

```
[----foo-----][[-bar1-][bar2]]
```

I.e. two columns each half the width, and then in the second column two sub-column with a 3/5 and 2/5 split, I do something like:

```
<div>
  <div id="left-section" class="half-width">
     Foo <!-- lots of content -->
  </div>
  <div id="right-section" class="half-width">
     <div id="three-fifths-of-this-section" class="three-fifths-width">
          Bar1 <!-- lots of content -->
     </div>
     <div id="two-fifths-of-this-section" class="two-fifths-width">   
          Bar 2 <!-- lots of content -->
      </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

with the following CSS

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .half-width {
    width: 50%;
    *width: 49.9690%;
  }


  .three-fifths-width {
    width: 60%;
    *width: 59.969%
  }

  .two-fifths-width {
    width: 40%;
    *width: 39.9690%;
  }
}
```

Why is the `three-fifths-width` class computed as 60% of the **screen** width (and `two-fifths-width` as 40% of the entire screen)? It's just a regular CSS `width` property which should be 60% (or 40%) of the **parent** element and so 30% (10% resp.) of the screen in practice.

By the way I am actually using [PureCSS](http://purecss.io) in practice but I'm interested in the underlying CSS.

Also, I aware that the `min-width` within the `@media` query is always relative to the screen, I'm asking about a regular `width` or even `min-width` as a CSS rule within the scope of a `@media` query.

Comment: Please provide a live example of this

Comment: I don't have a live example, but I updated the question to explain the column layout that I'm after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how your browser renders your output, but first of all it shouldn't be anywhere near 60% or even 30% due to the fact that you apply

```
display: inline-block;
```

to *all* `div` elements.

This causes two things: (1) your divs will only be as wide as necessary to display its content and (2) whitespace between inline elements may cause unwanted effects. Therefore, your example looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8jrewj71/.

Note, that I have added your code twice and applied different classes to the parent `div` to see the difference between your CSS being inside a media query and not.

Now, if we add

```
.media, .nomedia { display: block; }
```

we get a complete different picture: http://jsfiddle.net/n4aw8pcd/

As long as the preview/result window is small enough, the media query part looks like before. However, as soon as the viewport exceeds 48em, it looks exactly the same as the part without media queries below.

Long story short: The answer to your question must be, it doesn't. `width: 100%;` is relative to the next parent element with a width property.

Comment: So yes the `div { display: inline-block; }` was just a mistake, I meant to only apply to the inner divs

Comment: Still, even with the outer divs being block elements, the calculations are as intended (see my second demo).

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure why I thought they were relative to screen originally!